# Do i hvae to import uikit and foundation framework both in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, uikit, foundation

When i create .swift file then Foundation framework is implemented by default.
But when i have to use UIKit framework then i also import UIKit framework.

I think UIKit contain foundation framework.
(kinda worry because of importing twice foundation framework.)

**which one is better code?**

#1 Just import UIKit framework.
import UIKit

#2 import both framework.
import Foundation
import UIKit

Are there any differences?

Comment: *Are there any differences?* - No, UIKit imports Foundation implicitly

Answer (score 1):

Yes UIKit contains Foundation, UIKit like the name implies adds UI elements. Foundation has mostly basic data types (strings, ints, dates etc.) and non GUI functions like print

[https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/][Foundation]
[https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit][UIKit]